# How do I write code to realize these tasks?

Tags: c#

I want to realize some async code in C# but I can't write. Give me a hint.

I have 4 tasks (task 0, task 1, task 2, task 3).

- Task 1 is after task 0.
- Task 3 is after task 2.
- Task 0 and Task 2 can be parallel.
- Task 1 and task 3 is done only one by one, that is, task 1 after task 3 or task 3 after task 1.

Then, how can I realize these tasks in C# code?

The following code is imperfect because Task 1 and task 3 should not be pallalel.

```
static Task WholeTask()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    tasks.Add(Task0and1());
    tasks.Add(Task2and3());
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

static async Task Task0and1()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Method0());
    await Task.Run(() => Method1());
}

static async Task Task2and3()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Method2());
    await Task.Run(() => Method3());
}

static void Method0()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("task 0 is completed");
}
static void Method1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("task 1 starts");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("task 1 is completed");
}
static void Method2()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("task 2 is completed");
}
static void Method3()
{
    Console.WriteLine("task 3 starts");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("task 3 is completed");
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WholeTask().Wait();
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply use a combination of `await` and maybe `Task.WhenAll`?

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Comment: @indirect_life Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Tasks have nothing to do with "parallelism". There is a task parallel library that helps with this.

Comment: I edited the code. Is this minimal reproducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 4 tasks

I'll define these as the following, since it's easier to see how the answers work:

```
Task Task0();
Task Task1();
Task Task2();
Task Task3();
```

> Task 1 is after task 0. Task 3 is after task 2.

You can compose (link/chain) tasks using `await`:

```
async Task Task0and1()
{
  await Task0();
  await Task1();
}

async Task Task2and3()
{
  await Task2();
  await Task3();
}
```

> Task 0 and Task 2 can be parallel.

Use `Task.WhenAll` for asynchronous concurrency:

```
var task0and1 = Task0and1();
var task2and3 = Task2and3();
await Task.WhenAll(task0and1, task2and3);
```

> Task 1 and task 3 is done only one by one, that is, task 1 after task 3 or task 3 after task 1.

Use `SemaphoreSlim` for an asynchronous-compatible lock:

```
private SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
async Task Task0and1()
{
  await Task0();
  await _mutex.WaitAsync();
  try { await Task1(); }
  finally { _mutex.Release(); }
}

async Task Task2and3()
{
  await Task2();
  await _mutex.WaitAsync();
  try { await Task3(); }
  finally { _mutex.Release(); }
}
```

Final code:

```
private SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
async Task Task0and1()
{
  await Task0();
  await _mutex.WaitAsync();
  try { await Task1(); }
  finally { _mutex.Release(); }
}

async Task Task2and3()
{
  await Task2();
  await _mutex.WaitAsync();
  try { await Task3(); }
  finally { _mutex.Release(); }
}

async Task WholeTask()
{
  var task0and1 = Task0and1();
  var task2and3 = Task2and3();
  await Task.WhenAll(task0and1, task2and3);
}
```

---

The above is only applicable if your tasks are actual asynchronous tasks. If your tasks are synchronous tasks, then you should use the synchronous equivalent of the above. Step by step, this would be:

> I have 4 tasks

I'll define these as the following:

```
void Task0();
void Task1();
void Task2();
void Task3();
```

> Task 1 is after task 0. Task 3 is after task 2.

You can compose (link/chain) functions by calling one after another:

```
void Task0and1()
{
  Task0();
  Task1();
}

void Task2and3()
{
  Task2();
  Task3();
}
```

> Task 0 and Task 2 can be parallel.

Use `Parallel` or PLINQ for parallelism. In this case, since we have two function to call, `Parallel.Invoke` is the natural choice:

```
Parallel.Invoke(task0and1, task2and3);
```

> Task 1 and task 3 is done only one by one, that is, task 1 after task 3 or task 3 after task 1.

Use `lock` for mutual exclusion:

```
private object _mutex = new object();
void Task0and1()
{
  Task0();
  lock (_mutex) { Task1(); }
}

void Task2and3()
{
  Task2();
  lock (_mutex) { Task3(); }
}
```

Final code:

```
private object _mutex = new object();
void Task0and1()
{
  Task0();
  lock (_mutex) { Task1(); }
}

void Task2and3()
{
  Task2();
  lock (_mutex) { Task3(); }
}

void WholeTask()
{
  Parallel.Invoke(task0and1, task2and3);
}
```

Comment: The tasks are not started at any point of the execution. If the method returns a new task every time this wont work, if you have to return the same instance of the task in every TaskX() call this would a do manual start to an existing reference or a mutable object that need to use locks to prevent parallel threads from requesting the same task at the same time. Mutable objects should rearly be used in parallel programing.

Comment: This code is written using the modern [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap), where tasks are always returned hot. So there's no need to start tasks. There's also no need for locks here, since no objects are shared (aside from the `SemaphoreSlim`, which is threadsafe).

Comment: Well sort of this will only work if the given that you wrap the method he posted in a Task.Run if not this will be called synchronously. And according to [this guy's :) blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) "One common mistake is to try to make asynchronous “wrappers” around existing synchronous methods.". That would run the task in a new thread.

Comment: Ah, I was reading the op as having asynchronous tasks. I've updated my answer to cover the synchronous case as well.

Comment: The question was a bit unclear on that and this will work, but I still think it would be better to avoid locks here. Would appreciate if you would take a look at my answer because I tried doing it lock free.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the building blocks that you need to solve your problem:

- [Chain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks) tasks 0 and 1, and also chain tasks 2 and 3.
- Use a [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) to protect the critical sections in tasks 1 and 3. This ensures that they are not executed in parallel.

Comment: Not criticising the answer, but out of curiosity: Would you suggest a lock over using await?

Comment: @user1781290: Not in general: They are two different tools for different (but sometimes overlapping) use cases. In the OP's case, it seems like the simplest solution to ensure that (a) 0+1 as well as 2+3 can run in parallel as efficiently as possible, but (b) 1 and 3 don't execute at the same time. If you have a solution that only uses await statements, I'd be curious to see it; feel free to add it as a competing answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work for you

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task0 = new Task(WorkWithSleep("task0"));
        var task1 = new Task(WorkWithSleep("task1"));
        var task2 = new Task(WorkWithSleep("task2"));
        var task3 = new Task(WorkWithSleep("task3"));


        var after0or2 = Task.WhenAny(task0, task2).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (if (task0 == t.Result)
            {
                Task.WhenAll(task2, task1).ContinueWith((tt) => task3.Start());
                task1.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                Task.WhenAll(task0, task3).ContinueWith((tt) => task1.Start());
                task3.Start();
            }
        });

        task0.Start();
        task2.Start();
        var allwork = Task.WhenAll(task0, task1, task2, task3);

        allwork.Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static Action WorkWithSleep(string name, int wait = 1000)
    {
        return () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Work:{name} STARTED:{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
            Thread.Sleep(wait); //This will simulate proccesor work
            Console.WriteLine($"Work:{name} ENDED:{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
        };
    }
```

You can play with wait times to see if this is what you want. But this is not something I would recommend because when doing processor intensive work a lot of optimizations can be done by writing case specific code and if you need to parallelize it probably takes too long and every optimization counts.

```
public static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            var task0 = Task.Run(WorkWithSleep("task0",5000));
            var task2 = Task.Run(WorkWithSleep("task2"));

            var task0or2 = await Task.WhenAny(task0, task2);

            if (task0or2 == task0)
            {
                WorkWithSleep("task1")(); //No need to do a run since the thred we are on in not buisy. and can just run on the same one
                await task2;
                WorkWithSleep("task3")();
            }
            else
            {
                WorkWithSleep("task3")();
                await task0;
                WorkWithSleep("task1")();
            }
        }
```

EDIT: made a change after reding the conditions.

EDIT2: Hanged from using mutable IsComplete to a reference check.

EDIT3: Added a proper async way to do it.

Comment: note that using the `Task` constructor is discouraged. There's some information regarding it [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html)

Comment: @Default God this guys blog again. He was singlehandedly responsible for starting that all tasks must have configure await nonsense that all the code analyzers put in. I would not recommend using this in real world apps since this is just POC and I could rewrite this with Task.Run, this would be a perfect use case for a Task constructor. And this guys blog is just nonsense because "I’ve written countless asynchronous and parallel applications, and I have never been in this situation." is not a good reason not to use something if you know what you are doing.

Comment: @FilipCordas you know he is the guy who quite literally [wrote the book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030171.do) on Asynchronous, Parallel, and Multithreaded Programming in C#

Comment: @ScottChamberlain didn't read the book so can't say if it's good or not. What I can tell you that on his blog he puts his opinions as facts and uses random theoretical examples to say never do something. His reasons They can only be used to create Delegate Tasks, never Promise Tasks.
They don't understand async lambdas.
They create Tasks in a "cold" or unstarted state, unlike every modern Task API. Don't apply to this console app since I did want to create delegate tasks, didn't want to do async Landa and I wanted a cold start because a task should not start before the other.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I might sounded a bit harsh I was overdramatic to be funny. There are great advice on Stephen Cleary's blog but every time I talk about tasks someone gives me his blog as a reference, and usually the point he is making is about desktop/client apps unrelated to the discussion like in this case.

Comment: "I wanted a cold start" - I recommend `Func<Task>` in that case. It's much less dangerous than the `Task` constructor.